# The numlock light is reversed

Tags: xorg

When the light is on the pad works, and vica versa. I can't see how to change this, I have tried restarting with the button pressed down while the computer is off, but that didn't work. I suspect my keyboard (a new, ultra slim one) is controlled by a micro chip, not a physical switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you plug in a second keyboard. Then change the numlock settings on that one. The light should stay the same on your original keyboard, but the computer will see it as having changed, back to the way it should be.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have observed this issue far too many times.  I thought it was my old keyboard, but with the new one: the same problem.

I work this around by pressing the numlock key so that the numeric pad *doesn't* type numbers (the light should be off, because it is reversed, as you said), then I just unplug and plug my keyboard: it is back in sync.

I am still not sure on when does this happens, but I believe it occurs when system is idle for a long time period.

Answer (score 0):

**On Ubuntu 16.04**

As a workaround,  tapping the <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> twice works to get it back in sync. I'd still like to know why this happens and how to insure that it doesn`t

Answer (score 0):

One reason might be that GNOME is set to remember the numlock status between boots, which can cause a mismatch.

Check from a terminal prompt with:-

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep -e numlock
```

It can be changed via an elevated terminal with:-

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.keyboard remember-numlock-state false
```

Test by rebooting.

See also
[GNOME bug tracker #62: numlock-state not saved/restored](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-flashback/-/issues/62)